# Are dropout adjustment screws necessary on an indoor trainer?

Tags: road-bike, frames, rear-wheel, dropouts, turbo-trainer

I have a 2007(?) Cervelo P2C with horizontal rear dropouts, and I noticed recently that one of the dropout adjustment screws had bent. I plan to replace it, but until I do so is there any issue with me putting the bike on my indoor trainer without the screws?

I know their primary purpose is to to keep the wheel centered and properly spaced from the frame, but that's obviously not an issue with a direct-drive trainer.

Mostly I just want to be sure I won't cause any damage by riding without the screws until I can replace them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. The screws aren't strictly necessary on or off the trainer. The clamping force of the quick-release skewer should be enough to secure the trainer or wheel to the frame.

Comment: Additionally, putting the bike on/off the trainer might have been the original cause of the damage.

Comment: @Criggie I was thinking that might have been the case since I never had an issue until I started using the trainer, but wasn't sure how exactly putting the bike on the trainer and taking it off might have caused it.